Did King Solomon (Shlomo HaMelekh) execute personally?
When Shlomo haMelekh ordered executions, did he carry them out personally or were they done by executioners?
(This question is especially about Shlomo and not other kings of Israel.)

In at least some cases the pesukim mention Shlomo ordering others to execute. And it doesn't make any sense for a king to do it personally. It would be far below his dignity.

Why do you ask?

Moshe rabbeinu handled such business personally.
And Yehoshua.
And Dovid.
All Israelite monarchs of dignity.
Is it undignified if he who passes the sentence does not swing the sword?
@N.T.

I'd say so. Even Hashem sends angels to fulfil many of His decrees
